# Inserting 200k records while parsing CSV locks up system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, csv

I'm trying to insert 200k records into three different tables. When I parse the CSV file and try to insert these records, Ruby locks up my entire system. Here is my code:

```
def upload_country
  @upload = Upload.new(:upload => params[:upload])
  if  @upload.save
  csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)

  csv.each_with_index do |row, index|
    unless row["name"].blank? or row["country_code"].blank? or row["destination"].blank? or row["code"].blank?
      @country = Country.new(:name => row["name"].gsub(/\s+/, " ").strip, :country_code => row["country_code"].gsub(/\s+/, " ").strip, :user_id => current_user.id, :subscriber_id => get_subscriber_id)
      @country.save

      if row["country_code"] == "1"
        p = @country.country_code.to_s+@destination.name+row["code"].gsub(/\s+/, " ").strip
      else
        p = @country.country_code.to_s+row["code"].gsub(/\s+/, " ").strip
      end

      @code = DestinationCode.create(:code => p, :country_destination_id => 1, :user_id => current_user.id)
    end
  end

  @upload.destroy
  @countries = Country.find_all_by_subscriber_id(get_subscriber_id)
  render :partial => '/mycarriers/carrier_country', :layout => false
end
```

Comment: The request takes long time to perform? creating 200k objects and insert them is probably not that fast. You should probably batch insert instead in some way.

Comment: @kashifali: how long did you leave it running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont use use Mass Insert here a [gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) that can help you in the quest I personally used it in my application to insert 500K records with [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) for the background processing

Hope it help you

Answer (score 1):

If you have long-running requests, it means that no other users can access your application at that time if you have only one rails instance running.

I would recommend you use `delayed_job gem` to do long processing task in the background. On the controller side, you should enqueue the job and `response 202 (Accepted)` to the browser. On the client side, you should periodically send the request to the server whether the job is finished or not. Then, update the ui accordingly.

Take [slideshare.net](http://www.slideshare.net) as an example. When the user finishes upload, slideshare redirect to the new page, and periodically update ui while it converts the presentation file.

An alternative solution is that you can run rake script in the background. Check out [this episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background) from railscasts.